# Custom YTD Option in HighStock Range Selector

Tags: highcharts

Using the [Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/markers-only) charting library, Is there any way using the Highstock Range selector to display a custom YTD option?

Current when you use a type of 'ytd' in the range selector, it defaults to using the calendar year. For my use case (and i would have thought for financial institutions as well) i need to display data running from 1st April - 31st March as a 'ytd' option

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not possible without hacking sources, find in Highstock:

```
else if (type === 'ytd') {
        now = new Date(dataMax);
        year = now.getFullYear();
        newMin = rangeMin = mathMax(dataMin || 0, Date.UTC(year, 0, 1));
        now = now.getTime();
        newMax = mathMin(dataMax || now, now);
    }
```

So as you can see, dates are hardcoded. You can change them to needed.

Comment: Thanks, i thought as much. As you're on the highcharts team, what's the changes of getting custom Date ranges added to a future version? :)

Comment: Actually, a non-hacky way of doing it would be to use the 'day' type , and use the count to calculate how many days you want to go back. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i've done it. Doesn't cope with looking at a previous Financial YTD (Which is a common use case for what i need it for), but i'm sure i could hack something up to do it.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8ceQ4/1/)

```
$(function() {   
var startDate  = new Date("April 01, 2012 00:00:00");
var today = new Date();

var count =  parseInt((today.getTime() - startDate)/(24*3600*1000)) -1;

$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'container'
        },
        rangeSelector : {
            selected: 1,
            buttonTheme: {
                width:100
            },
            buttons: [{                                                 
                    type: 'ytd',
                    count: 1,
                    text: 'Calendar YTD'
                },
                   {
                    type: 'day',
                    count: count,
                    text: 'Financial YTD'
                }]
        },
        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]            
    } );
});   
});
```

Comment: This may work in the OPs case, but I tried this for "July 1" instead of "April 1" and it goes back to "June 22" Huh? Also, I don't get dividing by `(24*3600*1000)`. In any case, I'm 'fraid this doesn't work as written.